# HP LoadRunner - measurements to watch outbound active TCP ports

Tags: windows-server-2003, measurement, ports, loadrunner

I am trying to find out if there are any relevant measurements that LoadRunner can track, when running a load test - where it can allow me to monitor the number of active outbound ports from a given windows 2003 box.

i am seeing that there are various measurements specific to CLR and IIS - such as current connections, but i am looking for something that can show the active outbound ports, at any given time, during the load test.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Analysis (v9.52) help file states that:

> The Connections graph shows the number
>   of open TCP/IP connections (y-axis) at
>   each point in time of the load test
>   scenario (x-axis). One HTML page may
>   cause the browser to open several
>   connections, when links on the page go
>   to different Web addresses. Two
>   connections are opened for each Web
>   server.

This is probably as close as you can get with the standard graphs in the analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take LoadRunner out of the picture for a moment.   All LoadRunner does is leverage the native capabilities of whatever operating system or application it is monitoring.   So, with the removal of LoadRunner, how would you monitor these items using perfmon or other utilities in Window.   Once you have that path set you should be able to educate LoadRunner to examine the same items.

Try this:

1. Run Performance Manager (Perfmon.exe)
2. Hit the '+' sign to add a measurement
3. Object = .net CLT Networking
4. Metric, Connections established

Similarly there are other counters present related to the network interface that may have some items of interest to you.   Once you have the counters you want, simply add them to LoadRunner's native capability to inquiry a Windows host or (preferred) set up a monitor group in SiteScope that LoadRunner Leverages.   Current releases of Loadrunner (at least since 8.x) ship with a 500 point SitScope license for use as a monitoring foundation.